# Restricting access in LAN network

Tags: networking, routing, ip, local-area-network

I'm just starting with networking and hope that someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to assign IP addresses to the network on the picture. I also need to restrict access from Lab Host1&2 to Admin Host and Intranet.

1.) I figured I can deny access to intranet using ACL list on router. Is that correct ?

2.) I don't know how to deny access from Host1&2 to admin. Should I use access list on a switch ? If so, I should set up VLANs first(therefore my addressation is wrong) in order for it to work?

Thanks in advance

[Topology and addressing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA9TN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely set VLANs if the router allows it and put computers to subnets according to who should see who on network